# sbt-native-packager plugin errors out rpm build of Play project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to package a Play Framework application using an RPM file and I do not know where to put the configuration that is required in the Play Framework project.

I have added the plugin to my project/plugins.sbt file

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "tomax repository" at "http://maven.tmx.com/nexus"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.6.3")
```

I get an error in Play when I run the following command:

```
rpm:package-bin
```

I then run the last command for the error as suggested and I get

```
Creating SPEC file: /projects/myproj/target/rpm/SPECS/MyProj.spec
[debug] Executing rpmbuild with: rpmbuild -bb --buildroot /projects/myproj/target/rpm/buildroot --define _topdir /projects/myproj/target/rpm --target noarch--Linux MyProj.spec
[error] error: line 4: Empty tag: Summary:
[info] Building target platforms: noarch--Linux
[info] Building for target noarch--Linux
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run rpmbuild, check output for details
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. I suggest you raise an issue with the sbt-native-packager project on github, after first checking that it has not already been raised by someone else.

Comment: The rpm-build prints its errors: "Empty tag: Summary" means the packageSummary is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to make the sbt-native-packager work with play is to add the following to your settings in Build.scala

```
val storeOpsServer = play.Project(
    "storeops-server", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("storeops-server")
  ).settings(
    //Packaging for RPMs
    name in Rpm := "my-server",
    version in Rpm := appVersion,
    rpmRelease := "0",
    packageSummary := "Some summary of your software",
    rpmVendor := "My Corporation",
    rpmUrl := Some("http://www.mycorp.com"),
    rpmLicense := Some("MIT"),
    packageDescription := "Some description of what your server does",
    rpmGroup := Some("Group")
  ).dependsOn(adapterApi)
```

You don't need all of the values above but these are the ones that I used and was successful with.

Here are the imports that were in the file

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.linux.{LinuxPackageMapping, LinuxSymlink}
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmDependencies
import com.typesafe.sbteclipse.core._
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
```

Comment: Great Answer!

Note: I'll be fixing the docs and error messages to outline when you try to build an rpm what the required values are.

Comment: Please include the imports required to make this work

Comment: Collin I added the imports to the answer thanks for pointing that out.  I love it when I see more complete answers.  Unfortunately our Build.scala is kind of complicated and has several projects in it.  Please comment if you need further help.